# make chrome settings shortcuts clickable

Tags: google-chrome

I have a [page](http://remusrigo.blogspot.com/2012/03/chrome-settingsshortcuts.html) that contains shortcuts to chrome settings and the links don't work. Does anyone how to fix this?

If you go to chrome://gpu, click on the profiling tab, the chrome://tracing link is working just fine.